# How can I display most liked posts from posts feed?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have a simple php script where users can post without logging in, after they submit post their posts are showing just bellow in posts feed, something like facebook's post/news feed. How can I now take three most liked posts and display them in another div section? Is that possible?

Index.php

```
<div class="comment-form-container">
            <form id="frm-comment">
                <div class="input-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="commentId"
                           placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field"
                           type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                    <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment"
                              id="comment" placeholder="Add a Comment">  </textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton"
                           value="Publish" /><div id="comment-message">Comments Added Successfully!</div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
            var totalLikes = 0;
            var totalUnlikes = 0;

            function postReply(commentId) {
                $('#commentId').val(commentId);
                $("#name").focus();
            }

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "comment-add.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                            listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                listComment();
            });

            function listComment() {
                $.post("comment-list.php",
                        function (data) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comment_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                                    {
                                        like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                           like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                                    }

                                    comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'>\ " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + commentId + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#output").html(list);
                        });
            }

            function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {

                for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                {

                    var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comment_id);
                    if (commentId == data[i].parent_comment_id)
                    {
                        if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                        {
                            like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                            like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                         like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                         like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        var comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'> " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                        var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                        var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                        list.append(item);
                        item.append(reply_list);
                        listReplies(data[i].comment_id, data, reply_list);
                    }
                }
            }

            function getLikesUnlikes(commentId)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'get-like-unlike.php',
                    data: {comment_id: commentId},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        totalLikes = data;
                    }

                });

            }


           function likeOrDislike(comment_id,like_unlike)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'comment-like-unlike.php',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {comment_id:comment_id,like_unlike:like_unlike},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("#likes_"+comment_id).text(data + " likes");

                        if (like_unlike == 1) { 
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                        if (like_unlike == -1) {
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            }



        </script>
```

comment-add.php

```
    <?php
    require_once ("db.php");
    $commentId = isset($_POST['comment_id']) ? $_POST['comment_id'] : "";
    $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : "";
    $commentSenderName = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_comment(parent_comment_id,comment,comment_sender_name,date) VALUES ('" . $commentId . "','" . $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (! $result) {
        $result = mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

comment-list.php

```
    <?php
require_once ("db.php");
$memberId = 1;
$sql = "SELECT tbl_comment.*,tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike FROM tbl_comment LEFT JOIN tbl_like_unlike ON tbl_comment.comment_id = tbl_like_unlike.comment_id AND member_id = " . $memberId . " ORDER BY tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike DESC, tbl_comment.date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$record_set = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($record_set, $row);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($record_set);
?>
```

So the posts are being displayed by most liked, but I want to take top three liked posts and display them in another div on a same page. Is this something I have to do in MySQL database or I can display it with just a code? Any help will mean a lot, I don't have a clue how to do this. And I know my code is open for SQL Injections, but I'll fix it before running it.

**I tried:**

```
                            var top3 = data.slice(1, 3);
for (var t = 0; (t < top3.length); t++)
{
   var commentId = top3[t]['comment_id'];
   parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                                    {
                                        like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='https://i.imgur.com/TIma1lr.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                           like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/TIma1lr.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                                    }

                                    comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                                <div class='posted-at'><font color='white'>at</font>&nbsp;" + data[i]['date'] + "</div><br /><br />\
                                            <blockquote contenteditable='true'><div class='comment-text'><q>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</q></div>\
                                           <cite><font color='white'>from</font>&nbsp;" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</cite></blockquote>\
                                               <div class='line'><span><i class='fas fa-rupee-sign fa-2x'></i></span></div>\
                                         <a class='btn-reply')'><font color='white'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fas fa-flag'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Report</font></a><a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'><font color='white'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fas fa-reply fa-rotate-180'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reply</font></a>\
                                            <div class='post-action'>\ " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + commentId + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
}
   $("#output2").html(list);
                        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember, this site is community driven. It's been two hours since you asked. Give folks some time. Also, please review [creating a minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you are asking is possible and your real question seems to boil down to, "how can I get the first three elements out of an array?" Think either `array_slice` or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function listComment() you have the list of comments in data variable. You are saying that it is already sorted by number of likes. So now you need to get the first (top) three elements of the array and print how ever you like it, like this:

after  $("#output").html(list);....

```
var top3 = data.slice(1, 3);
var list2 = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
for (var t = 0; (t < top3.length); t++)
{
   var commentId = top3[t]['comment_id'];
   var comment = top3[t];

   var out = '<li>Comment: ' + top3[t]['comment'] + '</li>';
   list2.append(out);

}
$("#output2").html(list2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it and it didint work, I guess im doing something wrong, I edited post with the code that I tried, if you can take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: you've mixed the code. The big loop is inside the small loop. My code is supposed to go inside the function listComment() ... after the line $("#output").html(list);

Comment: Oh, I mixed it, what should I put inside "var commentId = top3[t]['comment_id'];", did I put the right code?

Comment: inside the for loop i showed how to get the commentid from the comment. the rest is upto you how you want to present the comment. but this loop should come after you are done showing the main comments. top3[t] is a comment with all its properties.

Comment: Ill mark this as a answer, I will post reedited code of what I done, but nothings happening, i dunno why

Comment: You have to define an area in html where you want to show the 3 comments, like you have output div for main comments. Then inside the for loop you will create a string of html, just like you did for main comments. Once you have the string, you will put it inside the new DIV just you like did in the output div. You are missing where you want to show the 3 comments.

Comment: Okey so I added an div where I want it to be "output2" and I created sting inside for loop, and added rest of the code, I really dont know where im wrong now, but now the main comments are not showing aswell, sorry for being so boring, I re-edited the code

Comment: This is what console log is showing on data slice: VM1184:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: top3 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: don't append to the same list, make a new list. plus... don't use data[i] in your loop and html, use top3[t]

Comment: i have edited my answer to include a simple example.

Comment: Its just not working, when I add any code after $("#output").html(list);, whole code isnt working, and Im really stuck. I know this isnt a place where people code for you, but can you just add where the things should go, Im trying to figure this out for weeks and still cant achieve it.

Comment: can i see your code or whole page somewhere? is there a url to see? or a contact to reach you. i'd like to finish this off with a working code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you send me a mail to aleksaprebiracevicorona@outlook.com, and I can send you all the files or the ones that you need, there isnt a url since im running website on a xampp local server.